# Convert repeating decimal to fraction

Tags: javascript, decimal, fractions

I am using a button on a JavaScript scientific calculator to convert decimal to fractions via this code:

```
$('#button-frac').click(function(){
var factor; 

    // Finds the highest common factor of 2 numbers
    function highestCommonFactor() {
        for (factor = numerator; factor > 0; factor--) {
            if ((numerator % factor == 0) && (denominator % factor == 0)) {
                return factor;
            }
        }
    }

    // Enter a decimal to convert to a fraction
    var decimal = this.form.display.value;

    // Split the decimal
    var decimalArray = decimal.split(".");

    var leftDecimalPart = decimalArray[0];
    var rightDecimalPart = decimalArray[1];

    // Save decimal part only for later use
    var decimalOnly = "0." + rightDecimalPart;

    // Find the decimal multiplier
    var multiplier = "1";

    for (var i = 0; i < rightDecimalPart.length; i++) {
        multiplier += "0";
    }

    // Create numerator by multiplying the multiplier and decimal part together
    var numerator = Number(multiplier) * Number(decimalOnly);

    var denominator = multiplier;

    // Find the highest common factor for the numerator and denominator
    highestCommonFactor();

    // Simplify the fraction by dividing the numerator and denominator by the factor
    var numerator = Number(numerator) / Number(factor);
    var denominator = Number(denominator) / Number(factor);

    // Output as a mixed number fraction (depending on input)
    var mixedNumber = leftDecimalPart + " " + numerator + "/" + denominator;

    // Output as a proper fraction or improper fraction (depending on input)
    var numerator = numerator + (leftDecimalPart * denominator);
    var fraction = numerator + "/" + denominator;

    // Display solution in input #disp
    $('#disp').val(fraction);
});
```

This works well, but if the decimal is non-terminating and repeating the script crashes. Any idea how I might remedy this problem? Perhaps there's a way to check if a decimal repeats and to determine the length of the string that repeats, then take that string and express it over a number with equal number of digits, all 9s? Being relatively new to JavaScript, I am at a loss.

Comment: Can you transform your code to provide us a working example? That's a common rule in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Here's a fiddle: 
 
https://jsfiddle.net/4fbuyxqt/1

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Enter 1/3 and then the fraction button and you'll see my dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

Use this and round the decimal after at most 20 repeated chars.

```
Math.fraction=function(x){
return x?+x?x.toString().includes(".")?x.toString().replace(".","")/(function(a,b){return b?arguments.callee(b,a%b):a;})(x.toString().replace(".",""),"1"+"0".repeat(x.toString().split(".")[1].length))+"/"+("1"+"0".repeat(x.toString().split(".")[1].length))/(function(a,b){return b?arguments.callee(b,a%b):a;})(x.toString().replace(".",""),"1"+"0".repeat(x.toString().split(".")[1].length)):x+"/1":NaN:void 0;
}
```

Call it with `Math.fraction(2.56)`

It will:

- return NaN if the input is not a number
- return undefined if the input is undefined
- reduce the fraction
- return a `string` (use `Math.fraction(2.56).split("/")` for an array containing the numerator and denominator)

Please note that this uses the deprecated `arguments.callee`, and thus may be incompatible in some browsers.

Test it [here](https://ayunami2000.github.io/?html=&css=&js=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&tab=3)

Comment: How can I modify it in order round after 15 repeated chars?